# Error While I am converting Jhipster Project in to war using gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage

Tags: node.js, gradle, spring-boot, jhipster

I am trying to converting the Jhipster project in to war using this command , while i got the below error . The command is   `gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage`

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
        at new HTMLParser (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlparser.js:236:13)
        at minify (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlminifier.js:861:3)
        at Object.exports.minify (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlminifier.js:1216:10)
        at objectAssign.fileName (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp-htmlmin\index.js:22:39)
        at module.exports (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\tryit\tryit.js:8:9)
        at minifyHtml (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp-htmlmin\index.js:21:9)
        at Transform.htmlminTransform [as _transform] (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp-htmlmin\index.js:51:7)
        at Transform._read (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:159:10)
        at Transform._write (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:147:83)
        at doWrite (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:319:64)
        at writeOrBuffer (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:308:5)
        at Transform.Writable.write (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:246:11)
        at write (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
        at flow (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
        at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\kaisify-demo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
        at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    :gulpBuildWithOpts FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':gulpBuildWithOpts'.
    > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: It's probably an issue with your nodeJS environment but you don't provide enough details like jhipster version, node version.

Comment: Am using nodejs version: v4.4.3 and JHipster version: v3.2.1

Comment: OK, try deleting `node_modules` folder of your project and then run `nmp install`. You can also `run bower install` again, then re-try your build